# How do I kill one specific thread, not knowing it's reference?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

Let's say I have thread playing a sound every 10 seconds.
I also have a `settings` file, containing a certain amount of thread settings *(id, sound to play)*. My main script unpickles every thread setting, then starts as many threads with their own settings.

My question is, how do I kill one of those threads, and only one ? Not the first or the last, I'd want to have the ability to chose which one. Is it even possible ?

I thought about giving each thread a reference, but since I take them from the `settings` file, I don't know how many threads I'll have to start.

**Sound-playing thread:**

```
class MyThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, sound):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sound = sound
        self.stopped = False

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped:
            #Totally made up function, as an example
            playsound(self.sound)
            time.sleep(10)

    def stop(self):
        self.stopped = True
```

**Main script:**

```
threads = []
with open('settings', 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        try:
            threads.append(pickle.load(f))
            continue
        except EOFError:
            break

for i in range(threads)
    #Model of threads: [id, sound], [id, sound], [id, sound]...
    MyThread(i[1]).start()
```

Comment: Why not just keep a reference to the one you'll need to kill, then kill it?

Comment: @Carcigenicate My problem is that I'd want to give a reference to every thread, so that I could kill the one I want, but since I won't know how many threads there will be, I can't give a reference to each one of them (Or at least I don't know how !).

Comment: So you're creating many threads, and may need to kill them at some point in the future?

Comment: @Carcigenicate That's right, I'm creating as many threads as there are in the `settings` file, and I may need to kill a specific one later !

Comment: Then you'll need to keep track of what threads are doing what. A dictionary would be good for this. Also, look into alternatives to threads. I suspect you're overcomplicating this for yourself.

Comment: Also, `while not stopped:` won't work since `stopped` is a function. You likely meant `while not self._stop:`

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks, I edited it ! Though, this is a "model" of my original code, which is muuuch longer, those threads are necessary for my script !

Comment: @Carcigenicate Still, I don't get how I could have a full control over my threads through a dictionary...

Comment: Threads are necessary, but it's not necessary to use them directly. Rarely is manual management of threads a good idea. Threads are expensive to create, and error prone to maintain. The answer is, you'll need to track what threads are doing what. Like every programming problem, there's a million ways to do this. Using a dictionary that maps from a descriptive string to a thread might be a good start to try.

Comment: You say you want to kill a specific one, how do you want to decide which one to specifically kill?

Comment: The short answer to this question is "however you want". The ideal way is not to reach in from the outside and kill the thread but to program the thread itself to terminate when it's no longer needed. The reason you feel like you need to reach in and change what the thread is doing is that you didn't code it do what, and only why, you want it to do in the first place. Fix it, don't kill it.

Comment: @AlexHall the thread in itself is the same, but with different settings every time it is started, that's why I'd need to have the ability to stop one specific thread

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'll take a look at the doc about dictionaries, thanks

Comment: @sohomangue If you've never used dictionaries before, they really are a fundamental programming tool (they're called "maps" more generally). *DEFINITELY* understand how to use them if you don't already. I can't overstate that enough.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz every thread is actually an alarm, checking every five minutes if it's settings are matching the current hour, that's why I need to run my threads constantly, I can't terminate them when they end... cause they don't!

Comment: @sohomangue There is some circumstance that causes you to want to kill a thread. But that just means that you didn't code the thread right -- it should terminate when it has nothing left to do. Fix the thread to do what, and only what, you want it to do. Then you won't need to "reach in from the outside" to kill it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The thread stops itself after the alarm rings, that can be 8  hours later or in about 5 minutes, it all depends on the user's choice, that's why it must be stopped anytime; it's like a daemon thread, as it continuously executes a background task, which has no incidence if stopped abruptly

Comment: @sohomangue In other words, the thread keeps running even when it should stop. So fix it so it stops when it should stop. Don't try to reach in from the outside to make it do the right thing -- fix the bug so it does the right thing without needing such shenanigans.